# Using valgrind - "Invalid read of size 1" for strlen

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, valgrind, strlen

I'm trying to write code that sets the name of a Student object to a new name, but I'm coming across memory leak errors when creating a character array. I assume it has to do with /0 at the end of the array and isn't terminating properly, but I don't know how to properly fix this. Thanks for the help.

```
#include "student.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Student::Student(const char * const name, int perm) {
  this->setName(name);
  this->setPerm(perm);
}

int Student::getPerm() const {
  return this->perm;
}

const char * const Student::getName() const {
  return this->name;
}

void Student::setPerm(const int perm) {
  this->perm = perm;
}

void Student::setName(const char * const newName) {
  this->name = new char[strlen(newName)+1];
  // this->name[srtlen(newName)+1] = '/0';  <---- My suggested fix, but doesn't work
  strcpy(this->name,newName);

}


Student::Student(const Student &orig) {
  this->setName(orig.getName());
  this->setPerm(orig.getPerm());
}

Student::~Student() {
  delete this->name;
  this->perm = 0;
}
```

This is the valgrind error:

```
==13814== Invalid read of size 1
==13814==    at 0x4C2BA12: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:454)
==13814==    by 0x4F56FD6: UnknownInlinedFun (char_traits.h:267)
==13814==    by 0x4F56FD6: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.h:456)
==13814==    by 0x401ED8: Student::toString[abi:cxx11]() const (student.cpp:64)
==13814==    by 0x401A46: main (testStudent00.cpp:14)
==13814==  Address 0x5302e8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13814==
```

Comment: Use `std::string` rather than `const char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that you needed to add the 0 terminator is wrong, strcpy() will do that for you. Your attempt of doing so adds the 0 terminator one byte past the space you allocated (remember, array indexes start at zero), and the syntax is also wrong, you would need to do:

```
 this->name[strlen(newName)] = '\0';
```

However, to fix your memory leak You need to delete the previous string, like

```
void Student::setName(const char * const newName) 
{
   delete [] this->name;
   this->name = new char[strlen(newName)+1];
   strcpy(this->name,newName);
}

Student::Student(const Student &orig) : 
   name(0) {
  this->setName(orig.getName());
  this->setPerm(orig.getPerm());
}

Student::~Student() {
  delete [] this->name;
  this->perm = 0;
}
```

Now, for this to work, you also need to fix your constructor and copy constructor  to initialize the name member, so it isn't an uninitialized pointer for the first call to the setName() function, and you need to add an assignment operator too, so you can properly handle assignments.

```
Student::Student(const char * const name, int perm) :
  name(0) 
{
  this->setName(name);
  this->setPerm(perm);
}

Student &operator=(const Student &orig) {
  this->setName(orig.getName());
  this->setPerm(orig.getPerm());
}
```

Also, consider using [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) instead of your current low level way of handling strings, that way you don't need to even implement a copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor for this class, nor deal with correctly managing memory.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However, I tried deleting this->name right now and it created a larger memory error message during runtime.

Comment: You need to update your constructor too, see the new code.

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same errors. I changed to std::string and added the pointer initialization. I also tried adding an if statement saying if(this->name != NULL) then delete this->name, but it didn't help. Do you have any other ideas by any chance?

Comment: No, I don't know what kinds of error you are getting, I fixed your copy constructor too, added an assignment operator  and changed the code to the correct delete[] instead of delete. If you still  an issue, the issue is somewhere else. But please use a std::string in the future to avoid all these mistakes.